# image recognition and value verification from the value base python

Tags: opencv

I want recognize icon in game with transparency and background. The icons are in a certain position on the screen and have a slight transparency, and there is a background in the area of ​​the icon, which changes when the camera moves or rotates. I would like to determine what is in the image, but I don't know how to implement it correctly yet, maybe you have any ideas?

Here's what I got:
[image][image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.